# Laravel + Vue unable to save data to my database

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to save data from my vue component to database but it will just say 500 (internal server error ) on my dev tools.

I tried one by one deleting my code to see where it fails everything will work fine until the I added the save(); function to my database

**Vue Component**

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" v-model="fields.name" />
        <div v-if="errors && errors.name" class="text-danger">{{ errors.name[0] }}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post" id="post" v-model="fields.post" />
        <div v-if="errors && errors.post" class="text-danger">{{ errors.post[0] }}</div>
    </div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>

    <div v-if="success" class="alert alert-success mt-3">
        Message sent!
    </div>
</form>
```

**Vue COmponent Script**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: {},
      errors: {},
      success: false,
      loaded: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
  if (this.loaded) {
    this.loaded = false;
    this.success = false;
    this.errors = {};
    axios.post('/adminquickannc', this.fields).then(response => {
      this.fields = {}; //Clear input fields.
      this.loaded = true;
      this.success = true;
    }).catch(error => {
      this.loaded = true;
      if (error.response.status === 422) {
        this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
      }
    });
  }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**Controller** // My controller code to save it on the database

```
 use App\Post;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;  

 public function store(Request $request)
{
      // Validation 
      $this->validate($request, [
          'name' => 'required',
          'post' => 'required|max:500|min:10'
  ]);

  // Variables we needed
  $name = $request->input('name');
  $post = $request->input('post');


  // Saving the post to database 
  $post = new Post();
  $post->name = $name;
  $post->post = $post;
  $post->save();


}
```

I expect this code to save data to my database, is this way of saving it safe? and can you guys give me tools where errors like this can be more specific so i can understand where it fails Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: Can you please provide the details of the error, that would be easy for debugging.

Comment: We need to know the detailed error logs. Also `Internal Server Error 500` in this case usually is Laravel side problem.